# ng test close jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

When I run ng test tests are performed. But all I see is this:

[image]

though the console I see that all tests are performed.
[image]

page after tests reload. Why?
How do I see the test report in the browser?

I want to see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Click the debug button in the top right of the karma page, then right click > inspect on that page to open up the console. Is that what you want?

Comment: $ npm install protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter --save-dev use this

Comment: @SimonBriggs no it's not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add it in the config

```
client: {
    clearContext: false
},
```